# Struggling with LESS

Tags: javascript, css, less

I am trying to learn about LESS. After a very quick success on one site, I am now struggling on another while using pretty much the same code:

```
<link href="css/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/styles.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/less-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Should I change anything on the server to make it work?

Comment: Could you explain what isn't working?

Comment: it should look like this: belleandvidere.co.uk/ BUT looks like this belleandvidere.co.uk/dev/

Comment: Are you sure your relative urls are correct? did you possibly want `/css/styles.less`?

Comment: hi all, thanks for the advice. the css file was in the wrong place for a bit while i tried a few things. it is now in the right place again and i'll leave it there for now. (its here http://belleandvidere.co.uk/dev/css/styles.less)

Comment: @niceaddress: Your LESS file is a simple CSS file isn´t it?

Comment: for now yes, and once it is linked and working i was then going to start 'LESS'ing it. do you think that may be causing an issue?

Comment: IT WORKS!!! i found the problem, i had @charset "UTF-8" at the start and i think the @ symbol was confusing LESS...thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I get a 404 when trying to access your LESS file: http://belleandvidere.co.uk/dev/styles.less

Please check your path.

Answer (score 0):

At one point or another I ran into an issue with the *order* of the HTML properties (it shouldn't matter but it did).

I found that `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">` would work, while `<link href="styles.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css">` would not.

I'm pretty certain that less.js incorrectly checks for `<link>` elements. This may or may not still be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking the LESS JavaScript file before the LESS CSS Document.

I am assuming this due to the HTML DOM.

With the HTML DOM the HTML is loaded, the CSS is loaded, and then the JavaScript is loaded.

Try to place the script tag about the link tags.

Thanks,
I hope that helps.

Comment: i've tried this but it didn't work unfortunately. i looked out there for advice around this issue and the general recommendation seems to be to have them in the order i have written.

Comment: I definitely checked your code and couldn't even access the LESS file. Make sure you (1) Uploaded the LESS file and (2) Have the path correctly defined in the HTML Document.